# How do I get the return observer object value from Vuex getters?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

After I clicked the button, the button will intrigue the count() function.
The function is like below, which is written in computed object:

```
    computed: {
        
        // workable
        // ...mapState({
        //     account: state => state.account, 
        //     users: state => state.users.all}, ['samples']),
        ...mapState({
            account: state => state.account, 
            users: state => state.users.all,
            samples: state => state.samples
        }),
        count(){
            this.sampleJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters));
            console.log(this.sampleJSON);
        }
    },
```

In my console the function print an Observer object like this below:
[image]

It looks like a normal JSON object since I already used JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) function. However, as I used this.sampleJSON.sample.sampleId the result is undefined. I wonder why is that happening? Can anyone tell me how to get sampleId value from this Observer object? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried returning the state? Wouldn't it be wrapped inside of the observer object. If you don't return the state? (Sorry I'm more of a Pinia fan... Not great with VueX)

Answer (score 0):

```js
  computed: {
    sampleId() {
      return this.$store.getters['samples/all'].sample.sampleId
    }
  }
```

or

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('samples/all', ['sample']),
    sampleId() {
      return this.sample.sampleId
    }
  },
```